# Does Hibernate JPA support mysql InnoDB and MyISAM engines

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Do I need to annotate the java domain classes differently.
I have two tables one created with InnoDB and other with MyISAM.
The requirement is like that I could not create both with InnoDB.
I have created their domain java classes using JPA.
Now I am not sure, will my java code work properly as it works in case of InnoDB tables!

Comment: Which transaction level you have in your JPA configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same entity will work for both InnoDB and MyISAM, which means you do not need to change any annotation. The underlying DB details are transparent to your persistence layer code and that is what JPA provider does.

By the way, the question title "Does JPA XXX implementation support..." makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to annotate the java domain classes differently.

No You there no need to change java class. As i know if database is changed there is no impact on java classes they remain same only configuration files are changed like, url, dialect, username and password. In your case if you are changing your database engine from InnoDb to MyISAM then no change is required from java side. Although MyIsam doesnot support transaction you have to take care about your transaction.

Comment: Actually I am not thinking to have separate class for them. Current configuration is using InnoDB. Is it possible to use same configuration to fetch data from MyISAM table.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it should work without any change. What's more with properly done JPA mappings, you could even switch to totally different DBMS and it should work too.